# How to pass double and string values from activity to broadcast in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-broadcast

I am working on development of monitoring application for android phones which always run in background and automatically responds to SMS strings without interaction of user
I successfully got battery level and GPS coordinates in activity but cant pass these values from activity to broadcastreceiver which then auto send these values as reply to SMS strings.

Here is a code for passing value from activity class to broadcastreceiver class:

```
String info = "Battery Level: " + level + "%\n";
            setBatteryLevelText(info);

            Intent in = new Intent("my.action.string");
            in.putExtra("stat", info);
            startActivity(in);
            sendBroadcast(in);
```

code in broadcastreceiver class:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
String batt = getIntent().getStringExtra("stat");
if (bundle != null)
{
  //---retrieve the SMS message received---
  Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
  msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
  for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
      msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
      str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                    
      str2=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
      str += " :";
      str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
      str += "\n";      

    //---display the new SMS message---
      Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //  int number=Integer.parseInt(str2);
      SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

      String autoReplybat = "Battery";
      boolean isAutoReplybat = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString().equals(autoReplybat);
      if (!isAutoReplybat) {

          sms.sendTextMessage(str2, null,  batt, pi, null);
          }
```

Same problem with GPS coordinates(data type double)
I cant auto reply GPS coordinates and battery level. From my side empty msgs are automatically sent against SMS strings.
I guess problem is in passing values from activity to broadcastreceiver
kindly help me and correct my logical/syntax error
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 String batt = intent.getStringExtra("stat")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling getIntent() to retrieve the extras when you should be using the intent variable passed into the onReceive function.

**EDIT:**

At the top of your receiver you have:

```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          String batt = getIntent().getStringExtra("stat");
```

change this to:

```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          String batt = intent.getStringExtra("stat");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.action.string"); 
intent.putExtra("phonenum", "98588685959"); 
sendBroadcast(intent);

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  String action = intent.getAction();
  Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);
  if(action.equals("my.action.string")){
     String state = intent.getExtras().getString("phonenum");
 }
}
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.